# Обработка Post в Django

Tags: ajax, django, post

У меня есть список с чекбоксами. По нажатию на которые я отправляю Аяксом post-запрос. В итоге у меня получается вот такие данные в POST запросе:
[image: POST-запрос]

Проблема в том, что обрабатывается только 1 list_id, остальные нет. Не понимаю почему.

Представление:

```
def tddone(request):
    errore1 = 'Пост запрос есть'
    error2 = ''
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if 'list_id' in request.POST:
            for id in todolist.objects.all():
                list_id = request.POST.get('list_id')
                checked = todolist.objects.get(id=list_id)
                checked.save()
        else:
            error2 = 'Post запрос не содеожит list_id'
    else:
        errore1 = 'Post запроса нет'
    context = {'errore1': errore1, 'error2': error2,}
    return render_to_response('todo/tddone.html', context, RequestContext(request))
```

Модель:

```
class todolist(models.Model):
    text = models.CharField(max_length=140)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False)
    modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False)
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.id:
            self.created = datetime.datetime.today()
        self.modified = datetime.datetime.today()
        return super(todolist, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
    def __str__(self):  
        return self.text
```

Что нужно изменить, что бы работало все сохранялись.

Comment: А вы вывод post'а сделайте, скорее всего приходит только один `list_id`, если параметры переименовать в `list_id[]`, то должно отрабатывать как надо

Comment: @BOPOH А подскажите, что имеется ввиду _переименовать в list_id[]_

Comment: На вашей форме несколько элементов с одним и тем же `name` (`list_id`), надо заменить имена этих элементов на форме на `list_id[]`, тогда эти элементы будут передаваться все как массив

Comment: @BOPOH Да, но как в представление обрабатывать? Поставил в шаблоне `<input class="mdl-checkbox__input checkbox" id="{{ list.id }}" type="checkbox" name="list_id[]" value="{{ list.id }}">` , представление отвечает на это `Post запрос не содеожит list_id`

Comment: Я сразу написал: `а вы вывод post'а сделайте`, вашего кода у меня под рукой нет, проверить не могу что присылается, как это питон получит - не знаю, но все должно быть там

Comment: @BOPOH вот так выглядит post `csrfmiddlewaretoken=hoW21fOz4K8OGFY0ULxaKQa3lt3SGKph&list_id%5B%5D=85&list_id%5B%5D=99&list_id%5B%5D=109&list_id%5B%5D=111` . Вот так, если что я передаю запрос через Ajax `$(function(){
        $('.List').click(function(){
            $(this).hide(1000);
            $.ajax({
              url: "/todo/tddone/",
              type: "POST",
              data: $('#listform').serialize()
            });
            var fields = $('#listform').serialize();
            alert(fields);
        });
    });`

Comment: Надо показывать что видит питон, т.е. `request.POST`, а не то, что видите в браузере вы

Comment: @BOPOH Вот что содержиться в _request.POST_:  `<QueryDict: {'list_id[]': ['85', '99', '109', '111', '113'], 'csrfmiddlewaretoken': ['hoW21fOz4K8OGFY0ULxaKQa3lt3SGKph']}>`

Comment: А еще `request.POST.get('list_id')` содержит только последнее значение. Как сделать его массивом и сверить с id-шниками?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Посмотрел как это питон принимает, оказывается ваш первый вариант (т.е. `name=list_id`) для питона был вполне рабочим (для php он возвращал бы только один элемент, поэтому там требуется указывать `[]`).

Ошибка же в вашем исходном коде была следующая:

```
if 'list_id' in request.POST:
    for id in todolist.objects.all():
        list_id = request.POST.get('list_id')
        checked = todolist.objects.get(id=list_id)
        checked.save()
```

`request.POST.get` возвращает только одно значение (возможно, последнее). Чтобы получить весь список, необходимо вызвать: `request.POST.getlist()`

Но и в этом случае ваш код не будет работать верно, т.к. цикл `for id in todolist.objects.all()` вы нигде не используете и нигде не используется цикл по `list_id`. Вместо этого следовало написать следующее:

```
if 'list_id' in request.POST:
    for list_id in request.POST.getlist('list_id):
        checked = todolist.objects.get(id=list_id)
        checked.save()
```

Перед этим надо не забыть вернуть `name=list_id`

Comment: Спасибо. Это помогло. Понял несколько вещей из ответа.